# Android ABBY library - read engraved text

Tags: android, ocr, abbyy

I need to get text from engraved text on nameplate. I am using ABBYY sdk but still not able to detect all with accuracy. Please suggest any improvement to get text.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Vyoma

Comment: Add sample image please.

Comment: Hi, for reference sample image : http://www.idahofirearmsengraving.com/content/exampleImages/EngText/images/ScriptSample1085x1521.jpg